# Xcode6 beta 7 Swift cannot use UIPickerViewDataSource

Tags: xcode, swift, beta, uipickerviewdatasource

With Xcode6 beta 7 whenever i add the `UIPickerViewDataSource` in this way

```
class MyClassVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
```

it gives me a compile error saying

```
"Type MyClassVC does not conform to protocol UIPickerViewDataSource"
```

Obviously it worked with Beta 6, anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The various `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` methods declarations have been changed between Xcode 6 beta 6 and Xcode 6 beta 7. Why? Most of Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals parameters have been replaced with Optional or Non Optional parameters.

For example, the following declaration:

```
func pickerView(_: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return "Hello"
}
```

is now:

```
func pickerView(_: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return "Hello"
}
```

Check for your different `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` methods declarations in your `UIViewControllers`.

Comment: I've noticed this but why does it give me an error in the piece of code i posted? I didn't implemented the methods yet

Comment: You haven't implemented the methods yet? Well, that's *exactly* what the compile error is telling you. If you implement the methods, then MyClassVC will conform to the protocol. (Adding the declaration of the protocol after the class name "adopts" the protocol, which is a promise to conform to it. Adding the appropriate methods is the "conforming" bit.)

Comment: Totally right man xD was too much concentrated in checking what's different in Beta 7 that i forgot the common practices! Thank you